# Selecting Sets of Contiguous Events in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, sqlite

Okay so right now I'm working on a program that has a whole bunch of event objects. Each event object has a start time and end time (both full timestamps). A lot of the events are contiguous (one event's endTime is the same as the next event's startTime) showing that the two events happened in succession. **If I were to store all my events in a SQLite or MySQL table, would it be possible to query for each set of contiguous events?**

Say my table looks like this.

```
id   title          start_time           end_time
----------------------------------------------------------
1    Happy Time     4/3/2010 10:00:00    4/3/2010 13:00:00
2    Happier Time   4/3/2010 13:00:00    4/3/2010 18:00:00
3    Good Time      4/4/2010 18:00:00    4/4/2010 19:00:00
4    Gooder Time    4/4/2010 19:00:00    4/4/2010 22:00:00
5    Sad Time       4/6/2010 16:00:00    4/6/2010 20:00:00
```

I want to be able to query this table and see that id 1 and 2 are contiguous, id 3 and 4 are contiguous and id 5 is... contiguous with itself.

The reason I don't know where to start is because whenever I have worked with SQL queries, results were returned as individual rows. One row in the result is never part of a subgrouping.

If you have any questions feel free to comment. Thanks!

Comment: Are you guaranteed that events would be contiguous, or will some be overlapping? What result are you expecting from this, exactly, in all cases? Are you searching for potentially contiguous events, or just sorting them properly?

Comment: Overlapping - There are no overlapping events. Before the data is entered that is ensured.

Result - I am searching for contiguous events so I can perform a variety of operations on the block. Right now, I'm focusing on finding the total duration of the contiguous block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.start_time, a.end_time, b.id, b.title, b.start_time, b.end_time
FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE1 b
WHERE a.start_time = b.end_time
```

EDIT: modified based on the additional information:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.start_time, a.end_time, b.id, b.title, b.start_time, b.end_time
FROM TABLE1 a left join TABLE1 b ON a.start_time = b.end_time
```

Comment: The only problem with this query is that it leaves out events that do not have any other events contiguous with it. I would like to also select those. What's the best way to do that do you think?